# Entity Framework and changing table schema/structure

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, orm

I was wondering if someone knows if the following is somehow possible using EF or some other ORM.

We have a number of tables in a database. Like this one "Person"

```
Id
Name
Phone
Email
```

This is the same for all databases and will not change, it's our base table so to speak :)

Now one database might have a table also called "Person", it's the same but with an extra column **Phone**.

```
Id
Name
Phone
Email
Phone
```

Is there a way to have the Phone column available in the entity like a `Dictionary<string,object>`? I am actually only looking for basic select queries to support this. So I won't need a separate model for all databases.

Or is it just **not** possible? :)

-- 
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Linq To Sql or Linq To Entities are designed to work on static table schema, I'm afraid you'll have to use ADO.NET to get what you want, or go to another schema (FK from some other tables containing key values pairs for exemple)